# Get direct download link and file site from Mediafire.com

Tags: c#

For example, I have the link http://www.mediafire.com/?dr7j413wv5dc3n7t

What would be the best way to get the direkt download link, which is

> http://download656.mediafire.com/8qgjk46xjcag/dr7j413wv5dc3n7/Test.rar

and the file size (347.31 KB) in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way would be to use an HTML parser such as the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the HTML then query it.

It allows you to query the HTML using XPath, very much like `XmlDocument`.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a function already for my own use, here it is:

```
    public string Mediafire(string download)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req;
        HttpWebResponse res;
        string str = "";
        req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(download);
        res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        str = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        int indexurl = str.IndexOf("http://download");
        int indexend = GetNextIndexOf('"', str, indexurl);
        string direct = str.Substring(indexurl, indexend - indexurl);
        return direct;
    }
```

Then, the GetNextIndexOf function that is useful for cases other than just this. This is required in order for the Mediafire function to work:

```
    private int GetNextIndexOf(char c, string source, int start)
    {
        if(start < 0 || start > source.Length - 1) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        for(int i = start; i < source.Length; i++) {
            if(source[i] == c) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Lol, I didn't realize that perfect grammar was such a big factor when posting solutions. :P

Comment: Actually, having good grammar really is @user3596865. When someone sees poor grammar, it tends to turn them away from your answer. This is supposed to be a "professional" site and many users come on here for "professional" answers. Using incorrect grammar shows them that it is unprofessional, so it leads them to believe that your code isn't good in a professional setting.

Comment: Why have you used an entire separated "GetNextIndexOf" .. Using str.indexOf("\"",indexurl); should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should contact Mediafire to see if they provide an API.

I would guess that they don't have an API (atleast, not publicly accessable), which would lead to you needing to defeat CAPTCHAs and other anti-bot technology.

Trying to resolve a direct download link is likely against their terms of service, and may infact be illegal depending upon the laws where you're located.

Answer (score 1):

the Mediafire dnld code above works but you'll have to change to https rather than http and it still works:

```
public string Mediafire(string download)
{
    HttpWebRequest req;
    HttpWebResponse res;
    string str = "";
    req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(download);
    res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    str = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    int indexurl = str.IndexOf("https://download");
    int indexend = GetNextIndexOf('"', str, indexurl);
    string direct = str.Substring(indexurl, indexend - indexurl);
    return direct;
}
```

then use the webClient to do the actual download:

```
var client = new WebClient();
string mfdirect = Mediafire(mediafirexUrl);

client.DownloadFile(mfdirect, outputFile);
```

From below

> 

```
int indexurl = str.IndexOf("https://download");
                if (indexurl == -1 )
                {
                    indexurl = str.IndexOf("http://download");
                }
                int indexend = GetNextIndexOf('"', str, indexurl);
```

Comment: [`WebClient` isn't recommended for use anymore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-5.0#remarks), so I would avoid it.

Comment: Slight improvement since the download could still be an http://
  int indexurl = str.IndexOf("https://download");
                if (indexurl == -1 )
                {
                    indexurl = str.IndexOf("http://download");
                }
                int indexend = GetNextIndexOf('"', str, indexurl);

Answer (score 0):

Because the MediaFire direct download link is dynamic, there is a service for this kind of cloud direct download.

You can use this website which grabs the link dynamic from mediafire:
https://cdn.matix-media.net/direct-download

If you want to do it by your own, you should try to parse the HTML and get the `a` tag element with the two classes `input` and `popsok` then get `href` tag of this element.

as of August 3, 2020